# Simple algorithm to crop empty borders from an image by code?

Tags: c#, image-processing, unsafe

Currently I'm seeking for a rather fast and reasonably accurate algorithm in C#/.NET to do these steps in code:

1. Load an image into memory.
2. Starting from the color at position (0,0), find the unoccupied space.
3. Crop away this unnecessary space.

I've illustrated what I want to achieve:

[image: Example illustration]

What I can imagine is to get the color of the pixel at (0,0) and then do some `unsafe` line-by-line/column-by-column walking through all pixels until I meet a pixel with another color, then cut away the border.

I just fear that this is really really slow.

**So my question is:**

Are you aware of any quick algorithmns (ideally without any 3rd party libraries) to cut away "empty" borders from an in-memory image/bitmap?

Side-note: The algorithm should be "reasonable accurate", not 100% accurate. Some tolerance like one line too much or too few cropped would be way OK.

**Addition 1:**

I've just finished implementing my brute force algorithm in the simplest possible manner. [See the code over at Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/FADb57fq).

Comment: Only one way to find out.... seriously, I doubt checking 100x100 pixels is really *all that slow* in the long run.  Your typical processor runs 2,500,000,000 instructions per second.

Comment: OK, thanks @mellamokb, let's start, I'll try how it works. Stay tuned... :-)

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to find an algorithm that can examine all of the pixels in a section of an image without examining all of the pixels in a section of an image ;)

Comment: Maybe I only examine every n-th pixel (2nd or 3rd e.g.) to speed up things...

Comment: @Uwe: Then how would you guarantee what you're stripping away is truly "empty"?  You can't infer empty pixels from surrounding empty pixels.

Comment: @mellamokb The algorithm should be "reasonable accurate", not 100%. I'll give it a try and post the results here.

Comment: @Uwe: That's definitely something that should go in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know your image is centered, you might try walking diagonally ( ie (0,0), (1,1), ...(n,n) ) until you have a hit, then backtrack one line at a time checking until you find an "empty" line (in each dimension).  For the image you posted, it would cut a lot of comparisons.

You should be able to do that from 2 opposing corners concurrently to get some multi-core action.

Of course, hopefully you dont it the pathelogical case of 1 pixel wide line in the center of the image :)  Or the doubly pathological case of disconnected objects in your image such that the whole image is centered, but nothing crosses the diagonal.

One improvement you could make is to give your "hit color" some tolerance (adjustable maybe?)

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you are suggesting is a brute force algorithm and will work all the time for all type of images.

but for special cases like, subject image is centered and is a continuous blob of colors (as you have displayed in your example), binary sort kind of algorithm can be applied.

start from center line (0,length/2) and start in one direction at a time, examine the lines as we do in binary search.

do it for all the sides.

this will reduce complexity to log n to the base 2

Answer (score 1):

For starters, your current algorithm is basically the best possible.

If you want it to run faster, you could code it in c++. This tends to be more efficient than managed unsafe code.

If you stay in c#, you can parallel extensions to run it on multiple cores. That wont reduce the load on the machine but it will reduce the latency, if any.

If you happen to have a precomputed thumbnail for the image, you can apply your algo on the thumbnail first to get a rough idea.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can convert your bitmap to a `byte[]` using `LockBits()`, this will be much faster than `GetPixel()` and won't require you to go `unsafe`.

As long as you don't naively search the whole image and instead search one side at a time, you nailed the algorithm 95%. Just make you are not searching already cropped pixels, as this might actually make the algorithm worse than the naive one if you have two adjacent edges that crop a lot.

A binary search can improve a tiny bit, but it's not that significant as it will maybe save you a line of search for each direction in the best case scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Although i prefer the answer of Tarang, i'd like to give some hints on how to 'isolate' objects in an image by refering to a given foregroundcolor and backgroundcolor, which is called 'segmentation' and used when working in the field of 'optical inspection', where an image is not just cropped to some detected object but objects are counted and also measured, things you can measure on an object is area, contour, diameter etc..

First of all, usually you'll start really to walk through your image beginning at x/y coordinates 0,0 and walk from left to right and top to bottom until you'll find a pixel that has another value as the background. The sensitivity of the segmentation is given by defining the grayscale value of the background as well as the grayscale value of the foreground. You possibly will walk through the image as said, by coordinates, but from the programs view you'll just walk through an array of pixels. That means you'll have to deal with the formula that calculates the x/y coordinate to the pixel's index in the pixel array. This formula sure needs width and height of the image.

For your concern of cropping, i think when you've found the so called 'pivot point' of your foreground object, you'll usually walk along the found object by using a formula that detects neighbor pixels of the same foregeground value. If there is only one object to detect as in your case, it's easy to store those pixels coordinates that are north-most, east-most, south-most and west-most. These 4 coordinates mark the rectangle your object fits in. With this information you can calculate the new images (cropped image) width and height.